# How to solve t-distribution f0r standard deviation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently refreshing my statistics knowledge and I am struggling with simple algebra (sad, but true...).
Consider the t-formula:

$$\text{Interval} = \bar X \pm t_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\frac{S}{\sqrt{N}} $$

The first X should read as "XBAR", I was unable to create that symbol.
I would like to solve this formula for S and would be grateful if someone could show the steps.

Comment: What does $+/$ mean after $\bar{X}$?

Comment: @Radz It means an interval. As an example: A mean has a confidence interval like this: Mean 1 confidence interval is from 0.5 to 1.5. With more words: in 95% of all samples, the population mean is in the range from 0.5 to 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\text{Interval}$ is made up of 2 values, mainly, a lower value (say $I_{L}$) and an upper value (say $I_{U})$.

For $I_{L}$ we have $$I_{L}=\bar{X}-t_{\alpha/2}\frac{S}{\sqrt{N}}\\
\\
\Rightarrow t_{\alpha/2}\frac{S}{\sqrt{N}}=\bar{X}-I_{L}\\
\\
\Rightarrow S=\frac{\sqrt{N}}{t_{\alpha/2}}(\bar{X}-I_{L})$$

Similiarly, for $I_{U}$ we have $$I_{U}=\bar{X}+t_{\alpha/2}\frac{S}{\sqrt{N}}\\
\\
\Rightarrow t_{\alpha/2}\frac{S}{\sqrt{N}}=I_{U}-\bar{X}\\
\\
\Rightarrow S=\frac{\sqrt{N}}{t_{\alpha/2}}(I_{U}-\bar{X})\\
\\
\Rightarrow S=-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{t_{\alpha/2}}(\bar{X}-I_{U})$$

---

Consider the steps when using $I_{L}$.

We have $t_{\alpha/2}\frac{S}{\sqrt{N}}=\bar{X}-I_{L}$.

Now, have a look at $LHS=t_{\alpha/2}\frac{S}{\sqrt{N}}$. We need to make $S$ the subject of the formula, so, we need to get rid of term $\frac{t_{\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{N}}$. To do this, we simplify multiply the original term by its reciprocal, that is, by the term $\frac{\sqrt{N}}{t_{\alpha/2}}$. This works because $$\frac{t_{\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{N}}\times \frac{\sqrt{N}}{t_{\alpha/2}}=1.$$ Given that we have multiplied the $LHS$ by $\frac{\sqrt{N}}{t_{\alpha/2}}$, we need to multiply the $RHS=\bar{X}-I_{L}$ by the same quantity. This then yields the equation given ins Step 3.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you kindly explain which operation was used in your third step`?

Comment: Dear @Christian Sauer, I have added the operations in the solution itself. Another way of looking at the operations is that we are reversing the mathematical operations. For example, if we have $S\frac{X}{Y}=RHS$ and need to make $S$ the subject of the formula. Observe that $S$ is multiplied by $X$ and divided by $Y$. So, to make $S$ the subject we then divide both sides of the equation by $X$ and multiply by $Y$. This is equivalent to simply multiplying throughout by $\frac{Y}{X}$.

Comment: That explanation was very helpful. Thank you very much :)